# Mapear los elementos de un array que están dentro de otro array y hacer suma por elemento con javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

ya el código se mapeo lo que me falta es hacer un for o algo para hacer la suma por elemento, no que me sume todo en total

```
 Vue.config.devtools = true;
    const v1 =new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        vuetify: new Vuetify(),
        data(){
            return{
            casa :  Array,
            ens : Array,
            referencias: [
                //array(1)
                {nombre:'melisa', apellido:'carmona', 
                datos:[
                    {telefono :'claro', casa : 'medellín', tele :15},
                    {telefono :'claro', casa : 'medellín', tele :20}
                ]},
                //array(2)
                {nombre:'andres', apellido:'sosa', 
                datos:[
                    {telefono :'iphone', casa : 'amalfi', tele :2.0},
                    {telefono :'iphone', casa : 'amalfi', tele :9.0}
                ]},

            ]
            }
        },
        methods:{
            mapearArr(){
                    const datos = this.referencias.map((item) => {
                            return(item.datos);

                        });
                      const cantidades = datos.map((op)=>{
                         return op.map((element)=>{
                             return element.tele;

                         }); 
                      });



                        this.total = datos.reduce((total, item) => {
                        return total + item.reduce((total1, item1) =>{ 
                        total1 - item1.tele;
                    }, 0);

                },0);

            }
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const referencias = [
  //array(1)
  {
    nombre: 'melisa', apellido: 'carmona',
    datos: [
      { telefono: 'claro', casa: 'medellín', tele: 15 },
      { telefono: 'claro', casa: 'medellín', tele: 20 }
    ]
  },
  //array(2)
  {
    nombre: 'andres', apellido: 'sosa',
    datos: [
      { telefono: 'iphone', casa: 'amalfi', tele: 2.0 },
      { telefono: 'iphone', casa: 'amalfi', tele: 9.0 }
    ]
  },

]

const home = referencias.map((item) => {
  return item.datos;
});
console.info(home);

const ens1 = home.map((item) => {
  return item.map((element)=>{
    return element.telefono
  })
});
console.info(ens1);

const total = home.reduce((total,item)=>{
  return total + item.reduce((total1,item1)=>{
    return total1 + item1.tele
  },0)
}, 0)
console.info(total);
```

Estás tomando mal la lógica del array para los métodos `ens1` `total` ya que estás tomando El array Home como un array de objetos y no estás teniendo en cuenta que cada elemento de Home tiene 2 array más. Ahí te dejo el ejemplo.

Comment: pero quet tal si unes los dos arreglo y lo sumas con reduce,  estas gastando memoria, y el CPU te los va a venir a cobrar